# Meta Title Tags Problems

Tags: seo, google-search, html, search-results, meta-tags

We have a News website in dual language Bengali and English version. Recently, we propose to developer team to add meta title tags and they added meta title tags in HTML code as default News title. For example News title is "UNICEF gravely concerned over state of children in Rakhine" and Meta title is "UNICEF gravely concerned over state of children in Rakhine - Example News" They just use News Name at the ending of Meta Title Tags. It's default because we can't edit it from HTML coding. They didn't keep any option to edit or customize the Meta Title.

Meta Title Tags doesn't show in Browser Tabs Pop-up just News Title is showing at Browser Tabs Pop-up and when we search through News title in Google Search Engine that time only showing the News Title not Meta Title Tags at SERPs.

```
<meta name="title" content="UNICEF gravely concerned over state of children in Rakhine - Example News"/>
```

And also I have seen some reputed News site's they don't use any Meta Title in HTML coding. They just use News title.

Now my questions are:

1. How much important is to use Meta title at News Site?
2. Which method is using the developer team is this right or wrong?
3. If I don't use Meta Title as a separate Tags is there any harm to SEO?

I think that we are doing wrong. At this time what can I do?

Comment: I am confused. The title tag is not a meta tag. Are you referring to the title tag?

Comment: I know it that title tags is not Meta Tag but we implemented Meta Title at CMS but not showing at SERP, Browser Tabs & some of SEO Tools

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the approach is not as bad as you might think.

One of the things that I like about it, is the fact that you are never going to have duplicate meta title tags issues. I mean, how often you have two different news using the same headline?. Appending the “Example News” category is really good as well.

My only concern will be how you want the title tags to be displayed in SERPs? SERPS has limited space and your headlines might not show up as you would expect. Google for example, might decide to display a completely different title by choosing the page H1 or showing one of the Other subheadings as the meta title if it finds it appropriate or partially show the defined title tag.

In the browser tab though, you should be able to see your defined meta title tag always

[image]

If in the browser tab or in SERP  are only showing “ - Example News”, then there is certainly an error with the code.

If possible, you can ask the developers to allow you to setup the meta title tag yourself by adding an input field in the same page you write or fetch the news. This will be more complicated, depending on the way you acquire the content for the news.

Ultimately, the title tag is for you to propose the title but is alway up to the search engines to display what they believe will match their users queries best.